# Infragistics WebDropdown display issue

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, netadvantage

I installed Infragistics 2012 and added a WebDropdown to my web page. When I hover over the webdropdown the dropdown gets a little bigger and the arrow image disappears. This is for Internet Explorer.
When I try on Firefox the dropdown size stays same but the arrow disappears and I can not click on it. Any ideas?

PS: I have a virtual directory under IIS which points to the ig_res styles folder.[image]

Comment: NetAdvantage is a very specialised set of controls. I would recommend asking on their forums or using your support contract.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have the image that is being used for the hover image in your images folder within the style library.  The image should be named igdd_DropDownButtonHover.png and should be in ig_res/[styleset]/images.

If the image is indeed missing, you will need to copy it from the style libraries that Infragistics provides.  If the image is present you should use the network tools of the browser or fiddler to see what the response is from the server when that image is requested.